# select distinct one column and pick just one occurence out of the second one

Tags: oracle

I have the below data:

| id1 | id2 | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | p |
| 1 | b | q |
| 2 | c | q |
| 2 | d | q |
| 2 | e | q |

I want to select distinct `id1`. For `id2`, I just want the first occurrence - I don't care about the rest like this:

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | c |

Thanks!

Comment: How you are determining the first record? SQL Tables are unordered sets. Or do you need just any random record for id2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fairly simple:

```
select id1, min(id2) as id2
from that_table
group by id1
```